# Adding files to Assets folder. Android

Tags: android, file, android-studio, directory, android-assets

I'm using Assets folder for files storing. And added file

> ten_ways

manually to this folder. But when I display the list of files of this folder with the help of this code

```
AssetManager manager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        try {
            String[] files = manager.list("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),files[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Nothing is shown. I understand that it means that there's nothing in this folder, but why?

Here's the struct of the directories:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common mistake when using `Toast`. You forgot to show it:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),files[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```